# Value assigned more than once in single assignment

Tags: c#, ssis

I made script task that's downloading and saving on disk two spreadsheets from Google Drive using file ID and prepared URL address.

This is main() from my C# code, there are no things outside of it:

```
   public void Main()
    {
        string m_FileId = Dts.Variables["User::varFileId"].Value.ToString();
        string m_RemoteUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + m_FileId + "/export?format=xlsx";
        string m_FilePath = null;


        WebClient client = new WebClient();


        try
        {
            m_FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::varFileName"].Value.ToString();
            client.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(m_RemoteUrl), m_FilePath);
            m_FilePath = "";

            m_FileId = Dts.Variables["User::varFileId2"].Value.ToString();
            m_RemoteUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + m_FileId + "/export?format=xlsx";
            m_FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::varFileName2"].Value.ToString();

            client.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(m_RemoteUrl), m_FilePath);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "FileDownload", e.Message 
                                                    + "\r" + e.StackTrace 
                                                    + " \rUrl: " + m_RemoteUrl 
                                                    + " \rFilePath: " + m_FilePath 
                                                    + " \rPath: " + Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString()
                                                    + " \rFileName2: " + Dts.Variables["User::varFileName2"].Value.ToString()
                                                    , string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Problem occurs exactly on every second time I run this code and I don't know how to get rid of it. There's just exception in my script task. I'm printing all variables that are used in this code, and as you can see there's something wrong with `m_FilePath`, it's like multiplied despite of being printed just once.

```
[FileDownload] Error: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
at ST_84b63d1593dd449886eb2b32dff40b2d.ScriptMain.Main() 
Url: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/----------/export?format=xlsx 
FilePath: C:\Google Drive extract\ga_manual_cost_file.xlsxC:\Google Drive extract\ga_manual_cost_file.xlsx 
Path: C:\Google Drive extract\ga_manual_cost_file.xlsx 
FileName2: ga_manual_cost_file.xlsx
```

SSIS variables that I'm using are ReadOnly, and are used only in this script task(I tried running only this part of control flow), and their values are as follows:

[image: variables]

Comment: Are you sure, that Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString() contains only the path and NOT addirionally the filename? Your error message states "Path: C:\Google Drive extract\ga_manual_cost_file.xlsx" - which is the content of "Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString()" and it is a path AND a filename... however, no idea why it works the first time and crashes the second time

Comment: @Tyron78, you can see value of varFilePath on screenshot, it's clearly only path without file name

Comment: But then it seems that the parameter is changed elsewhere - at least according to your output

Comment: Could you try and use Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString() instead of m_filepath in your code? According to your error output, m_filepath contains the string twice where Dts.Variables["User::varFilePath"].Value.ToString() contains it only once.